# Как мне внести данные переменной в одинарные кавычки?

Tags: python

Создаю программу с функцией копирования сгенерированной информации в буфер обмена пользователя. Использую Pyperclip (если знаете что-то лучше, пишите). Мне надо поместить информацию переменной (случайно сгенерированное число) в переменную с типом str и в которой будут одинарные кавычки. Приведу ниже пример кода для понятности проблемы:

```
# libraries
import secrets
import pyperclip
# variables
pw_res = None
# code
def generate():
   pw_res = secrets.token_urlface(16) # это пароль (будем обозначать 1q-2w3e4r5t-6y)
def copy():
   pyperclip.copy(pw_res) #ТУТ ДОЛЖНА БЫТЬ ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ pw С ОДИНАРНЫМИ КАВЫЧКАМИ, НАПРИМЕР: pyperclip.copy('1234') - в буфере обмена будет 1234, а выводится None
```

Жду ответов!

Comment: сомнительная безопасность, конечно. Просто в функцию `copy` передай свою переменную

Comment: кавычки НЕ ЯВЛЯЮТСЯ частью переменной типа строка. С чего вы взяли, что там нужны одинарные кавычки? ``pyperclip.copy('1234')`` и ``pyperclip.copy("1234")`` - абсолютно одинаковы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def generate():
   pw_res = secrets.token_urlface(16) # это пароль (будем обозначать 1q-2w3e4r5t-6y)
```

`pw_res` тут - локальная переменная функции `generate`, она остаётся внутри функции, снаружи функции при этом ничего не меняется. Хотите менять глобальную переменную - явно это укажите:

```py
def generate():
   global pw_res
   pw_res = secrets.token_urlface(16) # это пароль (будем обозначать 1q-2w3e4r5t-6y)
```

Но вообще глобальные переменные это зло, лучше передавать параметры в функции в явном виде и получать результат тоже в явном виде:

```py
def generate():
   return secrets.token_urlface(16) # это пароль (будем обозначать 1q-2w3e4r5t-6y)

def copy(pw_res):
   pyperclip.copy(pw_res)

x = generate()
copy(x)

# или

copy(generate)
```

Comment: мне кажется автор так составил вопрос ввиду незнания основ, поэтому использование глобальных переменных не его вариант)

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Ну я дополнил )

Comment: CrazyElf, крепко пожимаю руку! Спасибо за решение проблемы! И кстати, @ClarkDevlin, можете посоветовать литературу или курсы для изучения основ Python? Если вы, конечно, не изучили Python по курсам института/колледжа.